# how to solve $\int\frac{x^2}{x^2+1}dx$ by using series

Tags: calculus, power-series

I want to solve $\int\frac{x^2}{x^2+1}dx$ by using series, but I did something wrong.

Correct solution:

\begin{align*}
\int\frac{x^2}{x^2+1}dx &= \int\frac{(x^2+1)-1}{x^2+1}dx \\
&= \int\left(1-\frac{1}{x^2+1}\right)dx\\
&= x-\arctan(x)+C\\
&= x-\left(x-\frac{x^3}{3}+\frac{x^5}{5}-\frac{x^7}{7}+\frac{x^9}{9}-\frac{x^{12}}{12}+\cdots\right)+C\\
&= C+\frac{x^3}{3}-\frac{x^5}{5}+\frac{x^7}{7}-\frac{x^9}{9}+\frac{x^{12}}{12}-\cdots
\end{align*}

My wrong solution:

\begin{align*}
\int\frac{x^2}{x^2+1}dx &= \int\frac{1}{1+(\frac{1}{x^2})}dx\\
&= \int\frac{1}{1+u}dx\text{ ; }u=\frac{1}{x^2}\\
&= \int\left(1-u+u^2-u^3+u^4-\cdots\right)dx\text{ ; }\frac{1}{x+1}=1-x+x^2-x^3+x^4-\cdots\\
&= \int\left(1-\frac{1}{x^2}+\frac{1}{x^4}-\frac{1}{x^6}+\frac{1}{x^8}-\cdots\right)dx\\
&= C+x+\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{3x^3}+\frac{1}{5x^5}-\frac{1}{7x^7}+\cdots\\
\end{align*}

What did I do wrong?
Why didn't I get the correct answer?

Comment: Your series above relies on $|x|$ being small, the series below relies on $|x|$ being large. Both look right, at a quick glance.

Comment: "I wanna solve" $\to $ "I want to solve". 3 characters more and it becomes good English :)

Comment: Note that for $x>1$, $$
\arctan x = \frac{\pi }{2} - x + \frac{1}{{3x^3 }} - \frac{1}{{5x^5 }} -  \cdots \,.
$$

Comment: The "real" solution is *not* using series, but direct integration !

Comment: @YvesDaoust And then a series expansion of the result; it's a sensible way to match up with a method where you do the series expansion first.

Comment: @Gary thank you, but how to proof this series?   

$arctanx=\frac{π}{2}−x+\frac{1}{3x^3}−\frac{1}{5x^5}+⋯$

Comment: @UWUgg Take the identity $\arctan x= \frac{\pi}{2}-\arctan\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$ ($x>0$) and use the Taylor series of $\arctan w$ with $w= \frac{1}{x}$ on the right-hand side. It will converge for $0<w \leq 1$, i.e., $x \geq 1$.

Answer (score 2):

Both series are good, but for different domains, Note that when we use this form of binomial expansion:
$$(1+y)^{-1}$$
we require $|y|<1$ and so in the first series it is valid for the domain of the arctan series, whilst the second one is valid for $|x|>1$ which is why there is a difference.

---

One thing to note is when you integrate make sure it is wrt the correct variable. if you make a substitution $u=f(x)$ you must calculate $du$

Comment: No, he's integrating with respect to $x$ only, just to show the series expansion he's using the substitution $u=\frac1{x^2}$.

Comment: Yep I just wanted to make sure